# '$routeProvider' not displaying the content of 'templateUrl' in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am setting up a project in Angular and am wanting to configure some routing. I am trying to achieve this via 'ngRoute'. However, the '$routeProvider' is not displaying the content of 'templateUrl', though, it loads up the controller just fine.

routes.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/",{template:"<div>I am here</div>",controller:"dashboardController"})
    .when("/userList",{templateUrl:"/views/userList.html",controller:"userListController"})
    .when("/createUser",{templateUrl:"/views/createUser.html",controller:"createUserController"})
    .otherwise({template:"Error 404 : Page not found ! "});
});
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('updatedAngularProject',['ngRoute']);
```

views/dashboard.html

```
<div>
        <h1 style="color:white;">fgsdgsdgsdgsdgsdgsgasdgdggasdfshfghfg</h1>
</div>
```

views/createUser.html

```
<h1>Create User</h1>
```

views/userList.html

```
<h1>User List</h1>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>Welcome To | Bootstrap Based Admin Template - Material Design</title>
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
    <link href="resources/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Waves Effect Css -->
    <link href="resources/plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Animation Css -->
    <link href="resources/plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Morris Chart Css-->
    <link href="resources/plugins/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- AdminBSB Themes. You can choose a theme from css/themes instead of get all themes -->
    <link href="resources/css/themes/all-themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Angular -->

    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <script src="services/mainService.js"></script>
    <script src="services/userListService.js"></script>
    <script src="services/createUserService.js"></script>
    <script src="services/dashboardService.js"></script>

    <script src="controllers/mainController.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/userListController.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/dashboardController.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/createUserController.js"></script>

    <script src="routes.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="updatedAngularProject">
<div class="menu">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a ng-href="#/">
                            <i class="material-icons">home</i>
                            <span>Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a ng-href="#/{{'createUser'}}">
                            <i class="material-icons">text_fields</i>
                            <span>Typography</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a ng-href="#/{{'userList'}}">
                            <i class="material-icons">layers</i>
                            <span>Helper Classes</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </div>
            <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the 3 controllers are working fine for they have 'console.logs' in them that print perfectly.

My folder structure is that routes.js, index.html, app.js and views(folder) are at the same level whilst all the 3 views are inside of the views folder.

Thanks.

PS : It is working fine now. Infact, it was working perfectly well before also. Its just that the data was being hidden behind the sidebar and the navbar.
Thanks anyways.

Comment: @LuninRoman nope. doesn't work.

Comment: Please, extend your question. Provide us with full index.html file.

Comment: As I see, you forgot to declare your app in the template, `<body ng-app="updatedAngularProject">`

Comment: @LuninRoman its there. I just forgot to copy it here.
It still is behaving the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you forgot to put [`<ng-view></ng-view>`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) directive into index.html. This is a place where angular should put your template content.

Comment: Okay, then, can you please give more information? What does it means `not displaying the content`? Any errors? Can you please also add your index.html file, please?

Comment: @iamrkcheers Do you mean to say you're receiving a 404 error?

Comment: no errors, nothing.
As I said the routing is working fine since its switching the different controllers.
Just the view part isn't working.

Comment: If you open a dev console, you should find request to `/views/userList.html`, is it loaded successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Status code 304 (Not modified) occurs due to caching.

Can you try injecting `$httpProvider` in your `app.js` and try setting the `no-cache` as given below?

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';

    $routeProvider
    .when("/",{template:"<div>I am here</div>",controller:"dashboardController"})
    .when("/userList",{templateUrl:"/views/userList.html",controller:"userListController"})
    .when("/createUser",{templateUrl:"/views/createUser.html",controller:"createUserController"})
    .otherwise({template:"Error 404 : Page not found ! "});
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @iamrkcheers I've updated the code to perform the same at the `app.js` level. Can you please try it?

Comment: what do you mean. could you please elaborate.

Comment: In my updated code, I've just injected the `httpProvider` module and tried to set the `cache` parameter to `no-cache`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add current directory reference (`./`) to template path while setting the routing up.

do bit modification in your routing as below,

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/",{template:"<div>I am here</div>",controller:"dashboardController"})
    .when("/userList",{templateUrl:"./views/userList.html",controller:"userListController"})
    .when("/createUser",{templateUrl:"./views/createUser.html",controller:"createUserController"})
    .otherwise({template:"Error 404 : Page not found ! "});
});
```

notice the change `/views/userList.html` => `./views/userList.html`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error was in your `ng-href` and routing for templates. The problem resolved when I changed `ng-href="{{'createUser'}}"` to `ng-href="#!/createUser"`, there might be a better way of fixing it, but this will do. The routing had to have `./` before urls, but it depends on when these partials/templates are located.

Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/z2rll9leOZUAqPkxFiRF?p=preview